# Direction of electric field and current

Tags: electricity, electric-current

What is the direction of electric field in electric circuit is it positive to negative or negative to positive? Is the direction of current same as the field?

Answer (score 2):

By convention the direction of the electric field is the direction of the force that a positive charge would experience if placed in the field. So it’s directed positive to negative.

The direction of conventional current, which is the flow of positive charge, is the same as the direction of the field. The flow of negative charge (electrons) is opposite to the direction of the field.

Hope this helps